Compound Bioactivity classification
I am trying to train a model to classify whether a compound is active or inactive looking at its SMILES. I have a table with 3 columns-InchiKey, SMILES, and activity-5300 rows in total -35 % of which is for testing. InChiKey and SMILES are inputs or features and activity is output either active or inactive.
I did try some algorithms:
I got Morgan's Fingerprints of 2048 with radius 2  size and trained classic ML models such as Random Forest or XGBOOST. They are giving fair results with 88% accuracy. However, the models are strongly overfitting.
To get better results, I am gonna try other options such as:

Retrieve Compound images using RdKit and train a CNN model to do binary classification.
Using SMILES as a string, train an LSTM model.
I also found out that I can get an adjacency matrix and train GNN to do the task. As I am not majoring in ChemoInformatics, I have no domain knowledge of how to get an adjacency matrix and what information to include in it ( whether adjacency matrix itself -nxn (n-number of atoms or nodes as I understood) matrix or add Hyrogens or Add Bond information). I am lost in this one.

Those who are majoring in this field or those who have worked on the same problem, please, share your opinions how to handle this problem better and achieve better results.
